# Use rules on list elements one by one

Tags: replacement, rule

I have two list

```mathematica
list1 = {1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 8, 7};
list2 = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
```

I want to build rule,`a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 2, d -> 4, e -> 1, f -> 1, g -> 8, h -> 7`,But this is too much trouble to write

If I want to do

```mathematica
list1 = {1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 8, 7};
list2 = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};

(a^2 + b + 4 c + 4 d + 5 e + 7 f + 9 g + h) /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, 
  c -> 2, d -> 4, e -> 1, f -> 1, g -> 8, h -> 7}
(a^2 + b + 4 c + 4 d + 5 e + 7 f + 9 g + h) /. (list2 -> list1)
```

[image]

Comment: `rules=Thread[list2->list1]`

Comment: Try also this: `Transpose[{list2, list1}] /. {x_, y_} -> (x -> y)` or this: `MapThread[Rule, {list2, list1}]`. Have fun!

Comment: Try also this: `Extract[Outer[Rule, list2, list1], Array[{#, #} &, Length[Outer[Rule, list2, list1]]]]`. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## How many ways?

Feel free to edit, this is a community Wiki post, so there is no reputation gain for anybody.

@cvgmt

```
Thread[list2->list1]
```

@AlexeiBoulbitch

```
Transpose[{list2, list1}] /. {x_, y_} -> (x -> y)
MapThread[Rule, {list2, list1}]
```

@rhermans

```
Rule@@@Transpose[{list2, list1}]
Inner[Rule,list2,list1,List]
```

@E. Chan-López

```
Extract[Outer[Rule, list2, list1], Array[{#, #} &, Length[Outer[Rule, list2, list1]]]]
```